# Limit and maximum: IVT

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

> Let $f$ be a function defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f(a) > 0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and that 
>   $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0 = \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$$
>   Show that $f$ achieves its maximum value on $\mathbb{R}$.

I think I have to apply the IVT, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Since $f$ is continuous, it attains its maximum on every compact set $K$. Choose an $N$ sufficiently large that

$$|x| > N \implies |f(x)| < \frac{1}{2} f(a)$$

Now consider the interval $[-N, N]$.

Comment: I have an idea.. let me type it!

Comment: Am I in the right direction?

Comment: @OrchidFibio Not really. The IVT probably isn't overly useful here. Instead, try to prove that the maximum that $f$ attains on $[-N, N]$ is a *global* maximum too.

Comment: @OrchidFibio If $x \notin [-N, N]$, then $|f(x)| < f(a) \le $ the max attained within $[-N, N]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Can you find an interval $[c,d]$ such that $|f(x)|<f(a)$ on $\Bbb R-[c,d]$? Then apply the Extreme Value Theorem.